# Phonegap : auto detect phone number not working in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

Auto detect phone numbers is not working in android. I have set 'detect-data-types' = true in `config.xml`. It is working perfectly in iOS.

My code in config.xml is:

```
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
```

I can see the phone numbers change to links, but upon clicking it, there is no effect - the dialer won't open.

Another thing is, it is working fine in Android when the build is taken using Phonegap build service. But due to some reasons, I can only use cordova local build. Android platform version I have installed in cordova is 3.6.4. I am using Cordova version 4.1.2.